# will locally extremal continuous function be constant

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function. Let us suppose that each point on the segment is either local maximum or local minimum for this function. Is this function a constant?

Comment: See [this](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.rae/1229619424&page=record).

Comment: Thank you, David. I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

By David Mitra the answer is contained in [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-33/issue-2/Functions-for-Which-All-Points-Are-Local-Extrema/rae/1229619424.full)